# Init UIView with array from UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UIView that gets init from a Viewcontroller, however, when I try to pass it an array the array comes back during the init. But if I make a button on the UIView and then check the passed array then I can see it is loaded in correctly. So my question is this, how might I pass an array to a UIView so that when the UIView is alloc'ed and init'ed I can have the array loaded in, not after.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: can you post code of what you've tried...  From the sound of it you need to make a new `initWithArray:(NSArray *)array` function that will save the array you are speaking of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your UIView subclass something like

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame dataArray:(NSArray*)array_ {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        myArray = array_;


    }
    return self;
}
```

And `myArray` supposed to be a field (or property) of your class.

Comment: why 'array_' instead of just 'array' ?

Comment: Yeah that trailing underscore is really bad style in my opinion. What most people use it for, and even some Apple example code does this, is to mark *instance* variables. Why break that habit and use it for method params? Very confusing.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it, guys. Maybe I need to post some more code here to get my style fixed :)